# Text not moving to new line after <hx> tags

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to get the paragraph text to start on a new line after the  tags that I'm using for my sybtitles, but I just can't get them to budge. I've tried display:block and giving it a right margin to occupy the entire div width but nothing seems to be working!

You can see an example post here:
http://vhbelvadi.com/2012/04/21/mozilla-boot-to-gecko-good-early-too-late/

As you can see at the very first subheading, there's some of the paragraph text right next to it and it all looks shabby and unorganised! I want the paragraph to start on a new line automatically, every time.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine to me.  Any chance your style sheet is being cached and you're just not seeing the updates?  If so, it might be worth applying the technique described [here](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/force-css-changes-to-go-live-immediately/) just in case.  I use it on various client sites and it's saved me a few headaches.